# How to change segments of lines in a file based on regex Linux

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file where each line begins with a specific logging info. Here is an example:

```
12-May 02:01:18:INFO:root:restapid=>someurlhere
12-May 02:01:19:INFO:root:response=>loremipsum
```

I want to catch these time info and replace it with the current date&time. I'am able to get the target part by using egrep but unfortunately I couldn't find a way to change it (It is probably because I'm not familiar with sed). How can I do that ? My egrep solution is the following:

```
egrep '^[0-9]+-[a-Z]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+'weblog.api
```

If I can manage this part, I want to assign this command to a function(or alias) in my bashrc and when I run it I want to change all the time info with current time by calling something like

```
sample_alias weblog.api
```

The desired output format is the following (Let's say right now time is 04 Feb 05:02:03. I believe I can get the time info by `date "+%y%m%d%H%M"` command)

```
    05-Feb 05:02:03:INFO:root:restapid=>someurlhere
    05-Feb 05:02:03:INFO:root:response=>loremipsum
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus sorry for that. I've edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat v1
12-May 02:01:18:INFO:root:restapid=>someurlhere
12-May 02:01:19:INFO:root:response=>loremipsum


sed 's/[0-9]*-[a-Z]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*/'"$(date +"%d-%b %H:%M:%S")"'/g' v1
05-Feb 06:21:30:INFO:root:restapid=>someurlhere
05-Feb 06:21:30:INFO:root:response=>loremipsum
```